# Pandas read_fwf removing leading and trailing whitespace

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using the following pandas code to read a file:

```
file = pd.read_fwf(
        invoicefile, 
        widths = widthslist, 
        names = nameslist,
        converters={h:str for h in nameslist})
```

However, it's removing leading whitespace, and also trailing. How can I keep that intact?

Comment: I am not finding a solution. It appears pandas will run a strip() on objects. Any chance you can try a work around? For example loop through the invoicefile to create your df as a list and then call pd.Dataframe() on your list.

Comment: Can you post a sample of your raw data, you could use `read_csv` or `read_table` to achieve what you want

Comment: was able to fix it! I used a designated character to fill any spaces before running read_fwf, then once I loaded the data frame I replaced that designated character with a space!