# Read a file, modify it, write it out, and then read it again - better options?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, file-io

I have a fixed width text file that I am trying to read in using pandas.read_fwf. As noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41558138/pandas-read-fwf-removing-leading-and-trailing-whitespace), this method removes leading and trailing whitespace. In order to get around that, I'd like to replace every whitespace character with some filler character, read the file in as a Dataframe, do my manipulation and editing, restore each filler character to a whitespace, and write the file back out as a text file.

First I manually replaced the whitespace with the tilde character (~) and then manually removed it at the end just using notepad and find/replace, but this is slow and definitely something Python should be able to do for me.

My current method is convoluted, but it does work. I essentially read the file in, make the whitespace replacements, write it out to a temp file, then read it back in to pandas as a fixed width file. Same thing in the opposite direction at the end of my program.

Reading stage (replacing whitespace with ~):

```
with open("input.txt") as inFile:
     txt1 = inFile.read().replace(" ", "~")
        
with open("input_temp.txt", 'w') as outFile:
    outFile.write(txt1)

with open("input_temp.txt") as inFile:
    df = pandas.read_fwf(inFile, widths=[8, 8, 8])
```

Writing stage (replacing ~ with whitespace):

```
with open("output_temp.txt", 'w') as outFile:
    np.savetxt(outFile, df.values, fmt='%s', delimiter='')
        
with open("output_temp.txt") as inFile:
    txt2 = inFile.read().replace("~", " ")

with open("output.txt", 'w') as outFile:
    outFile.write(txt2)
```

Efficiency/memory isn't a huge concern, but I would still like a better way of doing this.

Comment: You already have the data that's in `input_temp.txt` in the variable `txt1`; you should be able to pass `io.StringIO(txt1)` as the first argument to `pandas.read_fwf` instead of re-reading the freshly written file.

Comment: Do you aim at reading the data or to use read_fwf as an exercise ?

Comment: @chepner that was exactly what I was looking for, thank you! Is there a way to use 'io.StringIO' in my writing stage?

Comment: @0x0fba after getting it into a dataframe, I'm reading it and changing it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `io.StringIO` as a file-like object to read from

```
import io

with open("input.txt") as inFile:
     txt1 = io.StringIO(inFile.read().replace(" ", "~"))
        
df = pandas.read_fwf(txt1, widths=[8, 8, 8])
```

and to write to

```
out_text = io.StringIO()
np.savetxt(out_text, df.values, fmt='%s', delimiter='')
    
txt2 = out_text.getvalue().replace("~", " ")

with open("output.txt", 'w') as outFile:
    outFile.write(txt2)
```